# User, customer, admin account in 3 different tables?

Tags: database, database-design

In my web application I will have three types of accounts.

- User: for using the web application for free
- Customer: for advertising and getting a Company Logo
- Admin: for editing and deleting stuff

Should all these three be in separate tables or in one with a column named "account_type" where i can mark it as User, Customer or Admin?

What are the pros and cons for both? Is there a best practice for this?

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be useful to stay how the use cases relate to other things in your data model.  I.e. what is the link between Customer and Images, User/Admin as access.

Comment: I would say one table, but if there are a lot of different attributes for each role, you should think about differnt tables. You can mark the user with an id/enum, let's call it role. role=1 would be an user, role=2 would be a customer and role=3 would be an admin.  So you can easily extend your roles with a foreign key construct (like David Stratton said).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general, a `person` can be user, customer and admin -- so, I would start with a `Person` table with columns `IsCustomer`, `IsUser`, `IsAdmin`. Later (for fast search) you may decide to add separate tables  `Admin`, `Customers`, `Users` with FK to the `Person` table.

EDIT:

A typical case may be:

- 5 million users
- 1000 customers
- 10 admins

In general, having separate tables for customers and admins should speed-up any admin/customer related query.

Comment: Sometimes, users and customers have differents properties, so you need to split into 2 tables instead of putting optional columns in the same table.

Answer (score 10):

If a user can only be one type, you'd be better off with one table and a bit field for IsAdministrator, etc.

If a user can be of more than one account type, you should then have a different table with a foreign key,

sample structure (data sypes are SQL Server and suggested only)

**Users table**

- UserID - int
- Username - varchar(25)
- Password - varchar(25)
- Firstname -   varchar(50) etc...

**Roles table**

- RoleId - int
- Role Description - varchar(25)

**User_Roles table**

- UserId - int (with a foregin key to the Users table)
- RoleId int (foreign key to the Roles table)

Comment: I think I get you. One Account table for basic information shared by them all, then 3 different tables for each of them with specific information, then I link to them with a foreign_key in the basic table right?

Comment: I was thinking you meant one table for administrators and another for custmers with all repeating info. I read it wrong, didn't I?

Answer (score 2):

Pros and Cons vary based on the size and complexity of your system.

I would break it up into User, Role, UserResources

> **User** (would define basic information)
>
> **User Roles**
>
> - FK->RoleType
>
> **Role_Type**  (user, admin, customer, possibly permissions or you could break this out further).
>
> **UserResources** (media)
>
> - FK->User