# DB Design for Admins & Customers

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm creating a site who's users will include customers and different levels of Admins. What is the recommended practice or what would be the correct way of setting up the DB Tables for this?

Both Customers and Admins will have a username and password. Customers, though, will also have a CustomerCode and Location, and Admins will have different levels/roles.

Should they be separate objects? If yes, how should I be relating the two?

Thank you for any input.

Comment: A similar question is asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511782/user-customer-admin-account-in-3-different-tables

I'd recommend doing a few searches on here and Google. There are many examples that should provide an adequate solution for what you are looking for. I personally would Separate them into seperate tables. Any book on DBMS's and design will provide you with an adequate solution.

Comment: When you say different levels of admins, what do you mean?  Are there distinct privileges, e.g. "set time", "delete planet", ...?  Are there restrictions on the scopes of their actions, e.g. user, department, division, corporation, potted plants?

Comment: @user92546 More like the latter (but possibly distinct privileged too for the future)  - for example: a Sales Person can view/edit only his/her customers' submissions, a Designer can view/edit all customers' submissions.

Comment: @Becky - I've done systems where there was a corporate hierarchy defined: departments, subdivisions, divisions, corporations.  Then a table of functions: create widget, edit widget, ... .  Access to functions could be granted to users, and the access could be limited to arbitrary portions of the corporate hierarchy.  UDFs hid much of the dirty work so that you could easily ask "Can user 42 manage email for department 16?" without worrying about inheritance and the like.  It's a fair bit of work.

Comment: @user92546 I see what you are saying with managing permissions. Although my situation is not as extensive, I'd probably go with a similar approach with a tables such as Roles, AccountRoles, and RolesPermissions. I think I'm more unsure with the table setup, since the Customers have fields that the other users don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three major ways of dealing with mapping logical requirements like yours to DB tables - (1) using a single table for both users and admins, (2) using two separate tables, and (3) using three tables, one containing the common data among the two categories of users.

The first and the third ways are good for cases when customers and admins should sometimes be used interchangeably; the second way is better when it is not a concern. I prefer the #3, because it's the most normalized way of modeling the two kinds of users.

Comment: So it would be something like an Account table (accountid, username, password), Users (userid, accountid), Customers(customerid, customercode, location, accountid). Then I guess I need a Roles and AccountRoles table (accountid, roleid) and possibly RolesPermissions. Now my question would be how I know if the user is a customer or not - would I have another field in the account table determining the type, or would the customer be another Role. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Also, it seems with 3 tables, it's at least 2 steps to get a user's info - first check which type the user (either by role or another column) and based on that, select from either of the tables?

Comment: @Becky you got the table design right. You know what type an account is by running an outer join of the `account` table with the other two. If you see a non-null `customerid`, it's a customer; if you see a non-null `userid`, it's a user.

Comment: @Becky You can do a left-join query with three tables to get user's info or customer's info in a single step.